# Apply options only to one graph in a plot

Tags: plotting, options

Let's say I have this plot.

[image]

It was produced using two different `Plot3D` commands combined via `Show` in order to reduce the opacity of only one of them.

```
s[p0_] := Sign[Re[p0]] Sign[Im[p0]]

Show[Plot3D[s[rep0 + I imp0], {rep0, -1, 1}, {imp0, -1, 1}], 
 Plot3D[0, {rep0, -1, 1}, {imp0, -1, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.1]]]]
```

Obviously, it would have been nicer, to include both graphs in one `Plot3D` command like so,

```
Plot3D[{s[rep0 + I imp0],0}, {rep0, -1, 1}, {imp0, -1, 1}]
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to then apply the opacity setting only to the second graph. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to give a list to `PlotStyle`:

```
s[p0_] := Sign[Re[p0]] Sign[Im[p0]];
Plot3D[
  {s[rep0 + I imp0], 0},
  {rep0, -1, 1},
  {imp0, -1, 1},
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.1]]}
]
```

[image: DifferentStyles]

Comment: That was surprisingly simple. Thanks!